# If God is "Infinitely" Merciful, doesn't that mean that, in a philosophical way, everyone will be forgiven and given access to jannah?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, jannah

If God is "Infinetely" Merciful, doesn't that mean that everyone will be given access to jannah?

Let's say I have an infinite number of candies, and I'm also Infinitely generous, and a Kid ask me to give him a candy, and I refuse. Doesn't that annul me being infinitely generous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a philosophical perspective - alone - if God forgives one person then he must forgive everyone else or he is not merciful. If he forgives everyone then he is not Just.

Now, a just God cannot forgive, but a God who doesn't forgive can't be merciful.

Trying to reconcile God's different attributes almost always leads to incomprehensible situations as they appear to the ordinary human intellect to be in conflict. This is a well known problem with positive theology.

From a philosophical perspective, in my view, the only way to reconcile the two  is to argue that God's forgiveness is necessarily accompanied by a corresponding act of "*Compensation*." That is, whenever God forgives a person He necessarily compensates *everyone else* by increasing their rewards in just proportions. Furthermore, the forgiveness is qualified to only certain types of sins, i.e. those not involving un-justness between creation. By this act of compensation for only certain types of sins God is not unjust if He so desires to forgive as many as He desires.

From a religious perspective, there is already a concept of Huquq-ullah and Huquq-ul-ibaad and we are told that the former can be forgiven by God's mercy alone, but for the later the sinner must pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right if you consider Him **Merciful** (الرحيم) only. However, God is Merciful as well as **Just** (العدل). Both of these qualities hold simultaneously. Being Merciful should not overrule being Just.

The next world is created on the principle of merit:

> He created death and life so that He might test you, and find out
>   which of you is best in conduct. ([67:2](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/67:2))

The people who deserve paradise according to their performance in moral matters end up there and those who do not are destined for hell.

> the virtuous will dwell in bliss, whereas the wicked will be in Hell; ([82:13-14](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/82:14))

If He sends all to paradise then it would not be fair with all those who struggled hard to win paradise.

> Should We treat the true believers and the wrongdoers alike? What ails
>   you? How ill you judge! ([68:35-36](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/68:35))

Let's take your example. Suppose you set a criterion that whosoever finishes his homework in an hour gets a candy. Now, if you give a candy to a kid who didn't finish his homework then it would be unfair with those who did it.

Comment: From a philosophical perspective - alone - a Just god cannot forgive, but a  god who doesn't forgive can't be Merciful. This is a well-known problem in philosophy of religion.

Answer (score 0):

All Praise to Allah Swt and blessings of him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

Allah Swt is the most merciful and compassionate

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
>   **There are one hundred (parts of) mercy for Allah and He has sent down out of these one part of mercy upon the jinn and human beings and
>   animals and the insects, and it is because of this (one part) that
>   they love one another, show kindness to one another and even the beast
>   treats its young one with affection, and Allah has reserved ninety
>   nine parts of mercy with which He would treat His servants on the Day
>   of Resurrection**.([Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/50/22))

But Allah Swt also says in Quran [4:17,18](http://quran.com/4/17-18)

> **"Allah accept the repentance of those who do evil in ignorance and repent soon afterwards; to them will Allah turn in mercy: For Allah is
>   full of knowledge and wisdom.Of no effect is the repentance of those
>   who continue to do evil, until death faces one of them, and he says,
>   "Now have I repented indeed;" nor of those who die rejecting Faith:
>   for them have We prepared a punishment most grievous"**

If we sin Allah swt punishes us but because of his kindness he does not punish at the moment giving us enough time so we could realize and ask for his forgiveness and mercy but we have this time to ask mercy before our death,because Allah is also a judge(Al-Hakam) and (Al-Adl)which means the just ,he is fair to everyone.Now if we believe that He is so kind that He will forgive all sins it can lead us to wrong path.If Allah forgives all sins people will have no reason to stop doing bad deeds,If a judge forgives everyone this world will be full of bad people then,"**And not equal are the good deed and the bad"**[41:34](http://quran.com/41/34).If you do good would would get reward ,if you do bad ,you get a correction,if you do bad and really sorry and do repentance Allah Swt may forgive you as He is (Ar -Rahman) The Most Merciful.

"**Say: "To Allah. He has prescribed Mercy for Himself**."[6:12](http://quran.com/6/12)

Allah Swt and His messenger knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, God is "infinetely" Merciful, and Yes maybe everybody will be forgiving except few Who God has mentioned in the Quran himself at various places. The people who commit Shirk (associating partners with GOD) will not be forgiven.

Answer (score -1):

No one knows for sure. Many Muslims incorrectly associate people who enter hell into being there forever, however, that could and could not be the case. We do not know what Allah will do or for how long. For example, take this Ayah for instance:

[image]

> And [mention, O Muhammad], the Day when He will gather them together [and say], "O company of jinn, you have [misled] many of mankind." And their allies among mankind will say, "Our Lord, some of us made use of others, and we have [now] reached our term, which you appointed for us." He will say, "The Fire is your residence, wherein you will abide eternally, except for what Allah wills. Indeed, your Lord is Wise and Knowing." [6:128]

Notice the part where Allah Says about The devil himself (Jinn) who mislead humans and their allies, he definitely says eternally, but then ads the following part: `Except for what Allah Wills`. For all we know, Allah can just eradicate us all and eradicate heaven/hell altogether thus wishes to, we don't know any better and should never assume Allah to follow any specific set or regulations, as one of Allah's name is `الماكر` `The most cunning`.